# How to draw a MPAndroidChart in kotlin using data that retrieved from Google Sheets?

Tags: json, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I have the following code where I am trying to get data from Google Spreadsheets and create a Line Chart using MPAndroidChart in Kotlin. I could fetch the data successfully using the below code but since it's my first time using MPAndroidChart I have no idea how to use my data with the chart.

The chart I am trying to draw is, sales for each branch by month.

I have added the dependencies that are required to use MPAndroidChart.

```
class SalesData : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySalesDataBinding

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySalesDataBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val salesList = arrayListOf<SalesDataModel>()
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

        val url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/sdfdfEjAKcnDc7ulj3ongsdfdKGsdfdf8i1NbTOScPrwrrfre3r4/exec"
        val jsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            Response.Listener {
                val data = it.getJSONArray("items")
                for (i in 0 until data.length()) {
                    val salesJasonObject = data.getJSONObject(i)

                    val salesObject = SalesDataModel(
                        salesJasonObject.getString("Date"),
                        salesJasonObject.getString("Branch").trim(),
                        salesJasonObject.getString("SaleAmount").trim().toIntOrNull(),
                    )

                    salesList.add(salesObject)
                }

                val datad = LineData(salesList,)

                Toast.makeText(this@SalesData, "Data loaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }, Response.ErrorListener
            {
                Toast.makeText(this@SalesData, it.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        ) {
            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                return super.getHeaders()
            }
        }

        Toast.makeText(this@SalesData, "Fetching data...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest) 

    }
}
```

Following is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SalesData">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
            android:id="@+id/lineChart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If the question is just about creating the chart (and not about accessing Google Drive data) then please create a minimum example with some sample data that someone else could run, which doesn't rely on having access to your Google drive spreadsheet. Also, check the [MPAndroidChart documentation](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart/) for examples to try, then if you have something that doesn't work, ask a question about it here.

Comment: Tags should correspond to what is being asked. In this case, [tag:google-sheets] should not be used because the question asks nothing about Google Sheets.